# eclipse - JPA entities from tables, no schemas listed

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jpa, mariadb

I have a database (called "socializer") residing within MariaDB server and I'm trying to generate JPA entities from tables of that database in Eclipse, but cannot, because [schema selection is grayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zXFp.png). Any ideas why?

My setup: Eclipse Neon, Eclipse Link 2.5.2, MariaDB 10.1.19-1, Arch Linux.

I know that the connection to my database has been established, because I can see it [listed in Data Source Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFKFB.png), but its "Schemas" folder is displayed just empty, although it actually contains a few tables, created and perfectly observed within MySQL Workbench (the other listed databases appear to have empty "Schemas" as well).

JDBC connection properties:

```
Database: "socializer"
URL: "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/socializer"
User name: root
Password: ""
```

JDBC driver (Generic JDBC Driver, mariadb-java-client-1.5.5.jar) properties:

```
Connection URL: "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/socializer"
Database Name: "socializer"
Driver Class: "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
User ID: "root"
```

And yes, user name and password are ok (ping will fail if either of them is changed).

Comment: please check the message under your connection you'll understand why

Comment: @KhalilM , if you mean "Generic JDBC Driver", then I don't think it is the case, because MariaDB, unlike "pure" MySQL is not a standard driver template in Eclipse, and I had to download the mentioned .jar and define the driver manually.

Comment: no I mean in the picture "you must have an active connection to select schema"

Comment: @KhalilM , but as I said, the connection is established (the database can be pinged and is listed within Data Source Explorer).

Comment: The key is that you do not see any schemas in the Data Source Explorer. Dali (the Eclipse JPA tooling plug-in) uses DTP (the Eclipse Data Tools plug-in). The Data Source Explorer is a view on the DTP model. If no schemas show up there, Dali will not find any schemas to display in the Entity Generation wizard. You might ask around the DTP project; but that project is fairly moribund....

Comment: @BrianVosburgh , thanks for your feedback. I narrowed my search request, according to your suggestions, and it seams to be a long-term bug in DTP's support of MySQL databases. That's why I just decided to use some other database system instead. I tried SQLite, and it interacts with Eclipse fine. Although it is of course just a workaround, not a solution of the problem.

Comment: I'm glad you have at least *something*. : ) But, yes, the DTP adapter for MySQL has long been a poorly-coded contribution that behaves differently from all the other database adapters. : (

Answer (score 6):

In Addition to the comments, I found another reason that might cause the problem, that no schema's are listed:

[image]

I run into this while trying to connect to another database with other schemas than before.

Go to *Project -> Properties -> JPA* and disable/uncheck *Override default schema from connection*

[image]

If there is a schema selected that doesn't exist in the selected database, no schemas will be shown when creating entities. For me the problem was, that Eclipse was trying to show a schema from the database before.

Answer (score 2):

In my case my database name was not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked For me....
Go to Go to **Project -> Properties -> JPA**

check both checkboxes

1. override default catlog from connection --> select ur connection
2. check default schema for connnection --> select ur schema

and done.. :)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.eclipse.org/datatools/downloads.php

install this plugin, i use 1.14.1 (Oxygen) version
then create new jpa tools, choice mysql

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm connecting to MySQL, and the problem is I need to add JDBC driver to Eclipse.

https://www.javahelps.com/2015/08/add-mysql-jdbc-driver-to-eclipse.html

Then when Eclipse asks you to select a connection profile, select the driver you added (MySQL for me, instead of Generic JDBC), and you should be able to see all schemas.