# Eclipse JPA connect to MySQL with Mac

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mysql-connector

I've created a local MySQL database instance, and connected to that instance using a connector. (I'm using mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar)
[image]

[image]

As you can see above, it all worked fine. Then the JPA properties are as the following. My database schemas are showing in catalog , but I cannot see any schemas. (ie. I can see 'dev' and 'sys' in catalog dropdowns, but schema dropdowns are always empty)
[image]

In the result of that, no matter how I tweak the JPA configuration properties, I cannot see any tables showing up in Data Source Explorer. Seems like it identifies my schema as catalog, and all tables in my schema are not showed. I want to be able to see all tables in schemas, and using JPA to auto generate class models from them.

If anyone has and ideas, I appreciate your help.
[image]

Comment: Good question. A few possible ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41093031/3368818

Comment: I think the problem is I need to add JDBC driver to Eclipse.

https://www.javahelps.com/2015/08/add-mysql-jdbc-driver-to-eclipse.html